# 13.04 nvidia GeForce 8800 GTS - no second monitor and other problems

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, 13.04

I have spent about an hour trying to find a solution to this, if someone has an answer or a link to an answer I would appreciate it.

I just wiped my disk (formerly running 12.04 LTS) and installed 13.04. My dual displays were working fine in 12.04, but when 13.04 came up I lacked my second display in the settings menu and the primary display is labelled "laptop" (I am running on a desktop). The only thing i can find when searching for a solution is a stack of complaints about nvidia drivers breaking unity and fixes for that which seem to be removing the nvidia drivers... so while installing the nvidia drivers seems like a good solution... it doesn’t look like the best course of action.

I appreciate any help, if anything is needed from me in order to find a solution please let me know.

Comment: Can you please see here if it solves your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-a-video-card-nvidia-ati-or-intel because I too have the same video card and using either of the versions you mentioned works correctly with 2 monitors and with unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install latest nvidia drivers

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-313-updates`

Enable nvidia drivers to manage your graphics

`sudo nvidia-xconfig`

Then execute

`sudo software-properties-gtk` which will show you a window like this

[image]

and select the latest driver from that list.

And then do

`sudo reboot`